# How does one go about building a system with which to Van Eck Phreak?

Tags: hardware, wireless, van-eck-phreaking

I've been reading plenty on the Internet about Van Eck Phreaking/TEMPEST and I'm curious as to how one might go about building a system to try it out. All I've found so far is [this website](http://eckbox.sourceforge.net/). It hasn't been updated in fourteen years. Is there just nothing out there for this? If so, why? It seems fairly straightforward.

I'm not up to anything nefarious. I kid you not, this is for a science fair project.

Comment: @schroeder It works on any electronic device with electromagnetic emissions. It has been demonstrated on LCD since then. Melissa Elliot (0xabad1dea) [spoke at DEFCON 21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N1C3WB8c0o) about doing this on a very poor quality laptop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're really talking about here is unintended electromagnetic emissions, and that goes way outside of the scope of grabbing monitor data via EM.

The main thing you're going to want to look at is [TempestSDR](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/tempestsdr-a-sdr-tool-for-eavesdropping-on-computer-screens-via-unintentionally-radiated-rf/). This is a project explicitly designed for doing exactly this kind of thing against real modern hardware. All you really need is an SDR, a decent antenna, and the software.

If you'd like further info and more cool stuff to take a look at, here's a huge link dump:

- Melissa Elliot abusing laptop shielding problems to dump screen data at DEFCON21: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N1C3WB8c0o
- The seminal paper on LCD TEMPEST: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/pet2004-fpd.pdf
- Making audio tunes with TEMPEST on a radio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLQbp6hj7-c
- In-browser TEMPEST test for CRTs: http://www.janschejbal.de/projekte/tempest/
- https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/ih98-tempest-old.pdf
- https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/0910/R08/work/slides-ykrt2-videorf.pdf

Then we've got more modern attacks against ICs and electronics in general using EMI probes and SDRs:

- https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Events/Non-Invasive-Attack-Testing-Workshop/documents/03_deBeer.pdf
- https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-811.pdf
- https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/thesis-182.pdf